# scrollable content w/ jquery

Tags: jquery, html, web

I am very new to jQuery, but I thought i would give it a go. So i have a footer, which i would like to be static on the page. I have a `<section>` where i have put a lot of text. I want this section to be scrollable so when scrolling only that moves up and down and not the footer.

So i have come up with this code so far?

```
 $("#main").mouseover(function(){
           $('#main').scroll();
       });
```

This is the beginning of the section

```
<section id="main">
         <div id="bio">
          <div class="section_separator">....
```

Hope i have made some sense? And you guys and help me out :)

Answer (score 0):

Set the footer's CSS to `position: fixed` (and probably `bottom: 0`)

Comment: That kind of works. But It doesnt allow the content to scroll behind it...it just scrolls over it.

Answer (score 0):

This is a CSS issue, not JQuery....

```
footer{
  position:fixed;
  bottom:0;
}
```

However, If you only want the page to scroll when you aren't hovering on top of the footer, this is what you want:

```
$('footer').hover(function(){
    $('html').addClass('scroll_disabled');
}, function(){
    $('html').removeClass('scroll_disabled');
});

$('html.scroll_disabled').on('mousewheel', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
});
```